# reference required for a well-known result

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry

Consider the following classic problem:

Given a 2-dimensional cube (a square) $[0,1]^2$, one of the minimum (area) simplex covering the 2-cube is bounded by $x_1 =0 , x_2=0, x_1+x_2 =2$.

For n-cube, **one of** the minimum (content) simplex covering the $n$-cube is bounded by $x_1 =0 ,\dots, x_{n}=0, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i =n$. And the minimum content is $\frac{n^n}{n!}$

There should be many references for this. Can you help me for some ?

Comment: There is another simplex of the same area 2 which covers the unit square, with its lower side the interval $[-1/2,3/2]$ (of the $x_1$ axis) and the third vertex at $(1/2,2).$ [Just saying there may be more than one simplex giving the minimal area...]

Comment: @coffeemath Good point !